# Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon

Tags: cypress, circleci

I'm getting this error when my circleci job is building my cypress test:

> [432:0312/154643.301773:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the
> bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No
> such file or directory [432:0312/154643.303582:ERROR:bus.cc(392)]
> Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon
> [432:0312/154643.303623:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the
> bus: Address does not contain a colon
> [619:0312/154643.361540:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not
> supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is

Does anyone know how I fix this?

Comment: The issue has been addressed in this GitHub thread: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19299

Answer (score 8):

Try these steps below:

**Install dbus if it's not installed**

```
# UBUNTU:
apt update && apt install -y dbus

# MAC: 
brew update && brew install dbus
```

**Then run the commands below**

```
# UBUNTU:
mkdir -p /var/run/dbus

dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address

# MAC: 
mkdir -p /var/run/dbus

dbus-daemon --config-file=/opt/homebrew/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address
```

Source: https://georgik.rocks/how-to-start-d-bus-in-docker-container/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is a known Cypress issue. See this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4925) from the official GitHub repo for more details.

These errors will still persist even if all the tests pass properly. I'm also getting similar errors with GitHub Actions. It seems like most users just ignore them. A user suggested a [fix](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4925#issuecomment-820843689) in April 2021 but there isn't consensus if it works or may cause other complications.

It seems like these errors are not helpful for troubleshooting because they happen even with the official Cypress actions when all specs are passing. If your tests are failing, these errors are likely not the reason.